# how to produce an artificially ping "request time out"

Tags: networking, network-programming, request, dos, ping

I want to produce a request time on internet of a machine, its for testing purpose for an application what happens when internet suddenly time outs.

**Updated**
system is windows server 2008, i want to do it manually just to check if the winform application keeps dispatching emails if there is a sudden ping break

Comment: You might want to add more information like the *programming language*? That would help... This is just a wild guess. It's like opening a question `how to program`. Give us some valid information, and we'll answer. If you don't, we can't answer.

Comment: I think the Wikipedia article on [ping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping) is a good starting point. Then continue with the [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) echo packet.

Comment: @TimS. added what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate it by (a) ignoring the reply, (b) filtering out the reply packet in firewall. Depends on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Could your developer not just throw a ping exception in their code? obviously you haven't mentioned the programming language as @Tim S commented, but in C# there is a `PingException` class - [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.pingexception.aspx) .